# Cost Analysis between the two enums in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-construction, enums

I came across an enum definition :-

```
typedef enum NSInteger {
    kBorderTypeNone   = 0,
    kBorderTypeLeft   = 1 << 0,
    kBorderTypeRight  = 1 << 1,
    kBorderTypeTop    = 1 << 2,
    kBorderTypeBottom = 1 << 3
} BorderType;
```

and also (possibly) it can be equivalent to

```
typedef enum NSInteger {
    kBorderTypeNone   = 0,
    kBorderTypeLeft   = 1 ,
    kBorderTypeRight  = 2,
    kBorderTypeTop    = 4,
    kBorderTypeBottom = 8
} BorderType;
```

What are the internal differences(if any)?
Is there any advantage of one over the other? 
Which one is recommended?

**Edit 1:**
If both are same then how compiler handles it? 
In which phase of compiler is it reduced to same set of instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the formats compiles to same. First one is efficient from easy programming point of view. Second one is more efficient during compilation time as it is direct assignment of value.

Answer (score 2):

They're the same, the former syntax is somewhat easier for adding more elements (linear number increase instead of powers of two).

Comment: they compile to 100% the same

Comment: If they compile to same then are the operations pre-optimized? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such difference. This enum is used as a flags and your first definition is much more readable in such cases.

```
typedef enum NSInteger {
    kBorderTypeNone   = 0,      // binary 0000
    kBorderTypeLeft   = 1 << 0, // binary 0001
    kBorderTypeRight  = 1 << 1, // binary 0010
    kBorderTypeTop    = 1 << 2, // binary 0100
    kBorderTypeBottom = 1 << 3  // binary 1000
} BorderType;
```

Also as [san's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798558/468724) suggest econd one is more efficient during processing as it is direct assignment of value.